# How do I use a "document.location.href" & in the same element have a button that doesn't activate it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

(I'm working on a mobile responsive website)

This is the list:

[image]

html:

```
                    <li url="http://google.com" class="mainli">NFL 
                        <img src="strokesmenu.png"   class="sub-menu" />
                        <ul class="sports2">
                            <li>Superbowl </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>

                    <li url="http://google.com" class="mainli">MLB Baseball  
                        <img src="strokesmenu.jpg"   class="sub-menu" />
                        <ul class="sports2">
                            <li>Playoff </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                <li class="mainli"> NBA  
                    <img src="strokesmenu.jpg"   class="sub-menu" />
                    <ul class="sports2">
                        <a href="#" class="selected"><li>Finals Playoff </li></a>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="mainli"> College Basketball  
                    <img src="strokesmenu.jpg"   class="sub-menu" />
                    <ul class="sports2">
                        <a href="#" class="selected"><li>March Madness </li></a>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li > Boxing  </li>
                <li> College Football  </li>
                <li class="mainli"> Golf   
                    <img src="strokesmenu.jpg"   class="sub-menu" />
                    <ul class="sports2">
                        <a href="#" class="selected"><li>British Open</li></a>
                        <a href="#" class="selected"><li>Masters</li></a>
                        <a href="#" class="selected"><li>PGA Championship</li></a>
                        <a href="#" class="selected"><li>US Open</li></a>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="mainli"> NHL  
                    <img src="strokesmenu.jpg"   class="sub-menu" />
                    <ul class="sports2">
                        <a href="#" class="selected"><li>Stanley Cup </li></a>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li> MMA   </li>
                <li> UFC   </li>
                <li> Soccer   </li>
                <li> Tennis   </li>
                <li class="mainli"> Horse Racing  
                    <img src="strokesmenu.jpg"   class="sub-menu" />
                    <ul class="sports2">
                        <li>Belmont Stakes</li>
                        <li>Kentucky Derby</li>
                        <li>Preakness Stakes</li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li> Other Sports </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

and these few onClick jQuery lines:

```
//first 
$('.sub-menu').click(function(){
        //$('.sports2').slideToggle("slow");
        $(this).parent().find('.sports2').slideToggle("slow");
    })



//second
    $("li").click(function(){
      document.location.href = $(this).attr('url');
    });
```

"NfL" is a link by itself - but if you press the #sub-menu button you have more categories with links. works for all the `<li>` in my html.

If I comment the second jQuery part - it opens the second list (the sub categories .sports2). but the links don't work.

If I comment the first jQuery code - I get the links working perfectly, but the submenus don't open.

How do I blend both without getting things mixed?

I tried uncommenting both of them - I get the links working fine, but when I click the #submenu button it expands for a second and immediately redirects to the link of the `<li url="...">`

Answer (score 0):

try to avoid links on different levels.
 (wich level will be triggered? li-toplevel or li-lowest level?)

Instaid of trigger your link event on ALL li also your toplayer, try using it on a li with a class reference like you did for '.sub-menu'

Answer (score 0):

When you click on a link or `.sub-menu` inside of `<li>` tag you're also clicking the `li` itself (have a look at example http://jsfiddle.net/op02x1qn/ and try clicking a link)

So one of the options is to get click event of exactly the item you want clicked. You can wrap your text inside of `li` like this (and style it css to be full width of parent element etc.):

```
<li class="mainli">
  <span class="mainli-text" data-url="http://google.com">NFL</span> 
  <img src="strokesmenu.png"   class="sub-menu" />
  <ul class="sports2">
    <li>Superbowl </li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

And JS:

```
$('.mainli-text').on('click',function(e){
   document.location.href = $(this).data('url');
});
```

So now when you click on something other than that new `span.mainli-text` inside of parent `li` it will have it's own click event.